# Jquery SlideUp Height

Tags: jquery, height, slideup

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#arrow').click(function () {
        if ($('#slide1').is(":hidden")) {
            $('#slide1').slideDown('medium');
        } else {
            $('#slide1').slideUp('normal');   
        }
    });
});
```

how can I mention the slideup height alone?

Comment: You may want to look at `animate` instead of `slideUp/slideDown` http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I tried with animate() but I didn't get the fruit which I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $('#arrow').click(function () {
      if ($('#slide1').hasClass("small")) {
         $('#slide1').animate({"height": "40px"}, "medium").removeClass("small"); 
      } else {

            $('#slide1').animate({"height": "20px"}, "medium").addClass("small");
      }
  });
```

You can use the `animate` method to change the `height`. And `hasClass` method to check the condition of the div(is it in the original size or not). Here I have added a class 'small' to indicate the reduced height state.

[click here for the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/xapCR/6/)

Comment: Still facing the same error. Your slides me up but it is not sliding down. My requirement is, onclick it has to perform two things:  SlideIp/down , change image. Below is the code which I'm using : $(document).ready(function() {
$('#arrow').click(function () {
      if ($('#slide1').hasClass("hdn")) {
         $('#slide1').animate({"height": "100px"}, "medium").removeClass("small"); 
      } else {

            $('#slide1').animate({"height": "60px"}, "medium").addClass("small");
      }
  });
  });

Comment: and for change image: var newsrc = "newdown.jpg";

function changeImage() {
  if ( newsrc == "newdown.jpg" ) {
    document.images["arrow"].src = "newdown.jpg";
    newsrc  = "newup.jpg";
  }
  else {
    document.images["arrow"].src = "newup.jpg";
    newsrc  = "newdown.jpg";
  }
}

Comment: Any idea on onhover image animate and change color of the image as like this: http://demo.highthemes.com/smartscreen/#  on top right corner social link images..

Comment: which one?sliding is done. Now I'm trying the onhover image concept and not yet started. The site which I sent to you is an sample for me.

Comment: that "right corner social link images" wont work in IE8 and below< I meant to say that animation of that social links. Place your mouse over it. And also that round corner wont work either

Comment: The problem is, I think that div corner is rounder by CSS3, CSS3 is not supported by IE8 and below, IE9 as well, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

Answer (score 0):

use `animate()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#arrow').click(function () {
      if ($('#slide1').is(":hidden")) {
       $('#slide1').animate({"height": "100px"}, "medium");
      } else {
       $('#slide1').animate({"height": "0px"}, "medium");;   
      }
  });
});
```

have a look to [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) (though deprecated and removed in jq 1.9),[`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It actually slides up with the specified height but when I click the same arrow button it is not sliding down.. Please help.